# Scroll the scrollview up when pickerview comes up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uipickerview

I have a form that I put inside a scrollview. On this form I have a couple of buttons that puts up a dateTime picker or a pickerView when I press on them. But I was wondering if I can but my form up to show the text that at the moment is behind the pickerView.

I know you can do that with a UITextfield. You can find the explanation over [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW7).

Hope that anyone can help me!

Kind regards!

Comment: chk my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620898/how-to-set-the-textview-move-up-animation-based-on-keyboard-in-the-custom-uiview/13621478#13621478

Comment: Answer is in your own question. You need to do set contentOffset of scroll view in action method of your buttons instead of doing it in keyBoard notification callbacks (as it is done in Apple docs you referred to)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
-(IBAction)btnDate_Clicked:(id)sender
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, -100, 320, yourScrollView.frame.size.height);  // set frame which you want   
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

and when you want to set original position of scroll then again set the scrollview frame with my animation code for ex.

```
-(IBAction)btnDone_Clicked:(id)sender
{

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    yourScrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, yourScrollView.frame.size.height);  // set frame which you want   
    [UIView commitAnimations];


}
```

Comment: This almost worked ! Only my pickerview goes up with the scrollview

Comment: @StefGeelen dude.. just add this pickeview in your self.view not a subview of scrollview mate.. jus add this in your view outside of scrollview..

Answer (score 0):

use the `scrollRectToVisible:animated:` method of `UIScrollView`